# Describing a Discrete Triangle Distribution Correctly?

Tags: variance

[image]I am trying to generate a sheet describing a discrete triangle distribution.  I think I have everything right, but I'd particularly appreciate someone telling me if I have the correct equation for the variance: (w^2 - 1)/6.

Comment: Since this is the distribution of the sum of two independent dice, its variance will be twice that of one die.  BTW, if by "range length" you mean the difference between the maximum and minimum value of the support, it's not $11$!

Answer (score 2):

Using @whuber's hint, discrete uniform distribution in $[a,b]$ has variance $$\operatorname{var}(Y)=\frac{(b-a+1)^2-1}{12}=\frac{w^2-1}{12}$$ twice the variance is $\frac{w^2-1}{6}$, as you calculated. You could as well calculate this using the conventional formulas, however I'd only recommend it for solely algebraical practice:
$$\begin{align}\operatorname{E}[X^2]&=\sum_{a+1}^{a+w}\frac{x-a}{w^2}x^2+\sum_{a+w+1}^{2w+a-1}\frac{2w+a-x}{w^2}x^2\end{align}$$